# the method to associate an array with a key in an existing complex hash structure

Tags: perl

I have two excel files. The first excel file is like this:

```
12   A    P1  
23   B    P5
24   C    P2
15   D    P1
06   E    P5
```

The second excel file is like this:

```
06 100
23 20
06 200
06 95
23 05
24 18
```

I want to generate the following data structure

```
$VAR1 = {
  'P5' => {
    'E' => '06' => [100, 200, 95]
    'B' => '23' => [20, 1000, 05, 30]
      },
      'P2' => {
        'C' => '24' => [18, 23, 2300, 3456]
  },
      'P1' => {
        'A' => '12' => [24, 25, 3200, 5668]
        'D' => '15' => [168]
      }
};
```

The first excel file enables me to generate the following data structure.

```
 $VAR1 = {
   'P5' => {
     'E' => '06',
     'B' => '23'
    },
    'P2' => {
      'C' => '24'
    },
    'P1' => {
      'A' => '12',
      'D' => '15'
    }
  };
```

What I did for implementing the above partial structure from the first excel file is as follows:

```
my %Var1;
for my $i (1 .. $row1)
{
    # for simplicity, I just keep the main part to building this hash chain
    $Var1{$column3}->{$column2} = {$column1};  
}
```

Here `$column3` relates to `p1`, `p2`, etc; `$column2` relates to `E`, `B`, etc and `$column1` relates to `06`,`23`,`24`,etc. The arrays associated with `$column1` will be extracted from the second excel file.

My question is how to iterate through this partially finished hash `%Var1`, and for each key, like `06`, to push `100` into it while traversing the second excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming (what im calling the numeric key ( the '06' in this example ) ) is unique then perhaps a function which returns the arrayref:

```
sub get_arrayref_from_nkey {
    my $target = shift;
    for my $pkey ( keys %Var1 ) {
        for my $akey ( keys %{ $Var1{$pkey} } ) {
            for my $nkey ( keys %{ $Var1{$pkey}->{$akey} } ) {
                if ( $nkey eq $target ) {
                    # return the arrayref to [ 100, 200, 95, .. ]
                    return @{ $Var1{$pkey}->{$akey}->{$nkey} };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

my $arrayref = get_arrayref_from_nkey('06');
push @{ $arrayref }, $value;    # 100
```

If the numeric key isn't found the function will return undef. Also if the numeric key isn't unique then this won't work - because it will return the first nkey it finds.

Comment: Also would recommend reading http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html for array/hash refs. It really helped me!

Comment: Richard, thanks for the reply. My question is this, assume we already have the partial hash structure from the first excel file. We strat to traverse the second excel file, the first line is 06  100.  First, we need to find the position of 06 in the existing partial hash structure, and append 100 to this key, 06. Since the existing hash structure is pretty complex, I do not know how to perform this key discovery operation. Thanks.

Comment: Can the key '06' appear in different sections?  eg P1 and P5 - or are the keys unique?